# PHP files are infected with SiteLock-PHP-CRYPTO.UNOFFICIAL FOUND

Tags: php, wordpress

My WordPress website is down because of some unwanted malicious code in `function.php`. I am not good at PHP programming so I am unable to find the affected code.

I already deleted the `social.png` file which is not actually image file, it is some PHP script code which affected the whole site. I Googled a lot and overflowed Stack Overflow with searches but none helped.

Comment: We discourage the use of pasteboards here, at least for the main question. I wanted to move the code in your link to the question itself, but since it is one or two thousand lines long, it's too big for here. That makes it rather too broad to answer, and in any case I am not sure what help you need. Your correct course of action is to wipe your server down (delete everything if you are on shared hosting, reinstall the operating system if you are on a dedicated server) and then restore files and databases from backup.

Comment: Nothing in there looks like "virus code". Chances are the malicious code was in the `images/social.png` file you deleted. More problematic is how they injected it - make sure your WordPress install is up-to-date, including all plugins, and you're probably best off restoring from a clean backup.

Comment: You will need to work out where you have a vulnerability too - it is either in this WordPress site, or in another website that runs under the same web server user. The core is usually safe, if you have been keeping it up to date - it's plugins and custom themes that you need to be careful of.

Answer (score 1):

Your website content is stored in a database so what you need to do is delete the whole of Wordpress from your server (Everything) and then reinstall wordpress from scratch. This will go some way to clearing up the mess.

Then at the same time change ALL of your usernames and passwords, just in case.

It may also be a good idea to download your images folder and scan it with MalwareByte - Anti Malware http://www.malwarebytes.org/3/ (free) to check the other images are "genuine", then restore them once the wordpress is reinstalled.